# UTC to EST convertion in JavaScript and also Daylight Savings capable

Tags: javascript, datetime, extjs, timezone

I have a small task with me to show the EST time irrespective of host system configuration using Javascript. This should also be capable of handling Daylight savings.
I have seen a few example which suggest to offset the difference time between UTC and EST.
This should be daylight savings capable. has to handle to offset to correct time.

or

Do you suggest to bring the time stamp from server side and print(I have idea related to this). And server time and date are set in EST time zone

But if it is possible to do it from Javascript i am looking forward for it.

please note this is not for the host configurated time and date. this should work irrespective of clients settigs

Thanks
Punith

Comment: I assume that by "EST" you really mean "Eastern Time", i.e. EST or EDT depending on the time of year?

Comment: yes.. that is absolutely correct.

Comment: Eastern Time (US and Canada). UTC -5.0 hrs

Comment: Well, UTC-5 in standard time, UTC-4 in daylight time. That's my point - "EST" really *is* only UTC-5, but that's not what you want.

Comment: yes, offsetting the time is fine. but how can we handle EST and Daylight time for a year. is there any inbuilt function available to know this ??

Comment: any possible solution in JS or am i in the wrong path to achieve it.??

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you before. I'm not a Javascript person, but a little bit of research suggests there's nothing in "stock" Javascript, although there are various third party libraries. Another option is potentially to use a web service.